# Insert images to Excel file with ExcelWriter() PHP

Tags: php, excel, spreadsheet-excel-writer

I'm exporting a data in **XLS format** with the use of **ExcelWriter() in PHP**. In some cases I have a data in **image format (stored as a path)**. is that possible to directly show images in the excel?

Comment: Are they stored as URLs?

Comment: Which ExcelWriter library are you asking about? Neither of the two libraries I'm aware of with that name (http://sourceforge.net/projects/excelwriterxml/ or http://excelwriterxml.sourceforge.net/) support images. Though there are a number of alternatives that do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do something like:

```
echo '<img src="' . $url . '" />';
```

Comment: how can i assign the cell height & width in Excel with escelwriter in php